# How does my https.post function know which function to call from API

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

My service file, which sends/gets data from mongoDB:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { filter, isEmpty, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  uri = 'http://localhost:4000/employees';
  data: Employee[];

  addEmployee(empObj) {
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, empObj).subscribe(res => { console.log('Done') })
    alert('Done adding data');
  }

  getEmployees(): Observable<Object> {

    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}`)
  }
  getEmployee(id: number): any {
    return this.http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/mpg19')
  }
  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
    console.log('ID of employee to be deleted', id);
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/delete/${id}`);
  }
}
```

And here is my file that performs CRUD operations.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const employeeRoute = express.Router();

let Employees = require('../models/Employee');


employeeRoute.route('/').post(function (req, res) {
    console.log('coming here', req.body)
    let employee = new Employees(req.body);
    console.log('data to save is: ', employee)
    employee.save().then(employee => { res.status(200).json({ 'employee': 'Employee added in successfully' }) })
})


employeeRoute.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('Employees Fetched');
    let employees = [];
    Employees.find({}, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            employees = results;
            res.json(employees);
        }
    })
})

employeeRoute.route('/delete/:id').get(function (req, res) {
    console.log('Delete Function Called')
    Employees.findByIdAndRemove({ id: req.params.id }), function (err, Employees) {
        console.log('Id against which employee is deleted: ', id);
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else res.json('Successfully removed');
    }
});
module.exports = employeeRoute
```

My application is getting and fetching the data properly, as I was following a written tutorial, I have a little confusion understanding the code. and that is:
how does my `addEmployee(empObj)` function (in first file) knows which function to call from the CRUD file.
Thanks is advance.

Comment: read more on REST patterns n practices will be clear

Comment: I already, googled, but still having confusion, thats why posted here.
If you have any useful resource for the said purpose, please provide me a link with that

Comment: Technically GET on this url http://localhost:4000/employees should give you a list POST on this url should add an employee thats what by defination on your second file is. 

GET on this http://localhost:4000/employees/:id should return single employee, PATCH or PUT on this http://localhost:4000/employees/:id should update details of employee and DELETE on http://localhost:4000/employees/:Id should delete employee from DB in your case you are choosing a custom route for DELETE on a GET request which is awful. Hope this makes sense

Comment: yes, my delete function is not working. what should I do to make it work
even though I'm now using `delete` http method

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: no error is displayed, it just don't delete the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things here you need to become more familiar with.

**HTTP Server vs HTTP Client**

Your HTTP Client is responsible for sending HTTP(s) requests to a server. When it dispatches this request, it usually has no way of knowing whether the server a) will accept the request or, b) what the server will do with the request. Therefore, when you call `http.post()`, your HTTP Client does not know what your server will do with that request. You can think of this as a message that your http client sends to a server with some instructions and details.

Your HTTP Server is responsible for accepting, validating and routing incoming requests as well as responding to those requests. Your server alone knows how it wants to handle incoming requests, and whether it will accept or deny them (or at least this is how it should be.)

You can learn more about how HTTP works here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview

**REST**

Just as your HTTP Client doesn't have any way of knowing what your server will do with a particular HTTP Request, so to are you (the developer) unable to easily reason with your HTTP Server and all of it's potentially valuable data. It is for this reason that REST aims to establish a set of principles designed around structuring content (or `resources`) on the internet, with reasonable ways of describing these resources and easy ways address these resources with common English Verbs (GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, etc... ).

You can read more about REST (and find related links) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/REST

**Express Routing**

Express acts as a software routing layer on your HTTP server. It's important to understand that this means express is responsible for creating and registering virtual routes on your server that point to resources. For example, when you do: `http.post('http://myserver.com/api/employees');` you are actually asking express (in this example) to try and find a registered route with the route path of 'api/employees' and respond with a resource (or resources) where appropriate.

Therefore, to answer your question directly - Angular's HTTP Client does not know which function will be run on your Express HTTP Server. Your Express Server uses the route `http://localhost:4000/employees` to determine what kind of resource you're asking for. In this case, it looks for a route registered to 'employees' and validates whether that route accepts the POSTs. If it does accept POSTs, then it executes the callback associated with that registered route.